# Star-Rating System html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rating

I'm currently working on a Guestbook and I would like to create a Star-Rating System. But I'm stuck!  I just can't fix the stars so that they stay yellow(gelb) when I click on them.

This is my code so far:

```
  <div class="rating">
        <p id="rating-paragraph">Rate</p>
        <img id="stern1" src="pictures/durchsichtig.png"  onmouseover="stern1.src='pictures/gelb.png'" onmouseout="stern1.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png'" alt="error"> <?php ?>
        <img id="stern2" src="pictures/durchsichtig.png"  onmouseover="stern1.src='pictures/gelb.png'; this.src='pictures/gelb.png'" onmouseout="stern1.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png'; this.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png'" alt="error">
        <img id="stern3" src="pictures/durchsichtig.png"  onmouseover="stern1.src='pictures/gelb.png'; stern2.src='pictures/gelb.png'; this.src='pictures/gelb.png' " onmouseout="stern1.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png';stern2.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png'; this.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png' " alt="error">
        <img id="stern4" src="pictures/durchsichtig.png"  onmouseover="stern1.src='pictures/gelb.png'; stern2.src='pictures/gelb.png'; stern3.src='pictures/gelb.png'; this.src='pictures/gelb.png' " onmouseout="stern1.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png';stern2.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png'; stern3.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png';this.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png' " alt="error">
        <img id="stern5" src="pictures/durchsichtig.png"  onmouseover="stern1.src='pictures/gelb.png'; stern2.src='pictures/gelb.png'; stern3.src='pictures/gelb.png'; stern4.src='pictures/gelb.png'; this.src='pictures/gelb.png' " onmouseout="stern1.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png';stern2.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png'; stern3.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png';stern4.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png'; this.src='pictures/durchsichtig.png' " alt="error">
    </div>
```

And css:

```
#stern1:hover, #stern2:hover, #stern3:hover, #stern4:hover, #stern5:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks for your time and maybe for some help or advice :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like you're missing a click event that will flip the images to make the the stars stay lit. You'll need an onclick or a JQuery $("#theId").on(click..... to get it go. [An Example](http://callmenick.com/post/five-star-rating-component-with-javascript-css)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pure CSS+HTML rating method without any images (works only with unicode charecter)

```css
div.stars {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<div class="stars">
  <form action="">
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
  </form>
</div>
```