# Display Star in Front End based on rating

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have created a field in backend
where using radio button am selecting the rating of product as 1 star, 2 star, 3 star, 4 star and 5 Star

In front end when displaying same

```
<p class="tool-tip"><a href="#" onMouseover="ddrivetip('Expert Rating')"; onMouseout="hideddrivetip()">Expert Rating</a> - <?php echo $this->prodDet->v_child_safety?></p>
```

It displays the rating in numeric form as - 1 star, 2 star, 3 star, 4 star and 5 Star

Can any one guide on the best way to have front end display a Star like rating instead of numeric value without making the page load slow

**This is not duplicate**
I just want users to view star type rating in front end
They can not modify rating or add a rating, its just that the administrator assigns a rating as 1 star to 5 star and its viewable in the front end
Now instead of numeric value as 2 star or 3 star i want stars to be displayed in

Thanks

Comment: http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Star-Rating System html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870635/star-rating-system-html)

Comment: Can I presume `$this->prodDet->v_child_safety` is replaced with `1 star` etc?

Comment: @Nimish I tend to disagree with the duplicate. It's not about a star rating system on its own. It's simply on how to display star images instead of text. There's no way to know if the visitors will ever be able to rate themselves.

Comment: @Ruchika Please answer my question above. Is `$this->prodDet->v_child_safety` replaced with `1 star` etc?

Comment: yes - its replaced with the value as stored in back end. if the value or product page in backend is stored 1 star then the output of $this->prodDet->v_child_safety will be 1 star

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on a solution for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure `$this->prodDet->v_child_safety` only returns a number. So instead of 1 star, 2 star, it should just return 1, 2, 3 etc. Then replace your code with this:

```
<?php

$stars = (int)$this->prodDet->v_child_safety;
$count = 1;
$result = "";

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    if($stars >= $count){
        $result .= "<span>&#x2605</span>";
    } else {
        $result .= "<span>&#x2606</span>";
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
<p class="tool-tip"><a href="#" onMouseover="ddrivetip('Expert Rating')"; onMouseout="hideddrivetip()">Expert Rating</a> - <?php echo $result?></p>
```

If you want to use images of a star instead, use this code:

```
<?php

$stars = (int)$this->prodDet->v_child_safety;
$result = "";

for($i = 1; $i <= $stars; $i++){
    $result .= "<img src='link_to_image_here.png'/>";
}
?>
<p class="tool-tip"><a href="#" onMouseover="ddrivetip('Expert Rating')"; onMouseout="hideddrivetip()">Expert Rating</a> - <?php echo $result?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks - but its always displaying in 5 Stars in front, despite having 1 or 2 or 3 rating in the backend. What could be the issue

Comment: @Ruchika Well the first code is supposed to display 5 stars. `&#x2605` and `&#x2606` are unicode characters. The first being a black star and the second being a white star with black borders. So if rating is 3 for example, it displays 3 black stars and 2 white ones after that. If the rating is 4, it would display 4 black stars and 1 white one.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses hidden radio buttons. The label is presented as a star thanks to fontAwesome. The value of the star can be sent to your PHP script or you can set the correct star based on any value you have.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  cursor: default;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <input id="star1" name="star" type="radio">
  <label for="star1"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <input id="star2" name="star" type="radio">
  <label for="star2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <input id="star3" name="star" type="radio" checked>
  <label for="star3"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
<!-- Use <?php echo("checked") ?> to set the correct star -->
  <input id="star4" name="star" type="radio">
  <label for="star4"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
  <input id="star5" name="star" type="radio">
  <label for="star5"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></label>
</form>
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. He doesn't want to get the rating. The rating is back-end only. He simply wants stars on the front end based on the rating that was set in the backend. Edit: That downvote did not come from me. Your answer can easily be turned into a good one imo.

Comment: My bad. I adjusted the code to indicate where PHP can be used to set the correct star. Not sure if the rating is to be adjusted. If not, it can be made read-only.

Comment: yes - i did not downvote too and why will i for people who want to help, i want only a stars to be displayed in front end based on the value

Answer (score 2):

Use below condition in each input:

`<?php if($this->prodDet->v_child_safety=="1 star"){?>checked="checked"<?php } ?>`

and use `disabled` to disable all input so that no one can change value if you just want to display rating.

```css
div.stars {
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input.star { display: none; }

label.star {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #444;
  transition: all .2s;
}

input.star:checked ~ label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
  color: #FD4;
  transition: all .25s;
}

input.star-5:checked ~ label.star:before {
  color: #FE7;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #952;
}

input.star-1:checked ~ label.star:before { color: #F62; }

label.star:hover { transform: rotate(-15deg) scale(1.3); }

label.star:before {
  content: '\2605';
}
```

```html
<p class="tool-tip"><a href="#">Expert Rating</a>
</p>
<div class="stars">
<input disabled class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input disabled class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" />
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input disabled class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input disabled class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input disabled class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" checked="checked"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is about displaying a value, not creating an input

There is a very simple way to do that supporting half stars, rounding to the closest half, using font awesome (v4 classes in code, v5 classes in comment) and some basic arithmetic

```
echo $rating;
echo "<span class='stars'>"
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
    if ( round( $rating - .25 ) >= $i ) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>"; //fas fa-star for v5
    } elseif ( round( $rating + .25 ) >= $i ) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o'></i>"; //fas fa-star-half-alt for v5
    } else {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>"; //far fa-star for v5
    }
}
echo '</span>';
```

Change the color of the icons

```
.stars {
    color: #ff7501;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

And voilà, you got yourself a rating display

[image: rating demo]

Answer (score 0):

Using this code, it's very simple and useful. 
Code is running successfully....

```
<?php 
    $select=4;
    $a=5-$select;
    $j=1;

    for ($i=1; $i<=$select; $i++) 
    { 
        echo "★"; 
        if($i==$select){
            for ($j=1; $j<=$a; $j++){
                echo "☆";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use data rating attribute like this

```
  <div class=\"star-rating\" data-rating= '".number_format($avg, 2, '.', '')."'>
```

[it displays like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMTvp.png)

and inside the double quotes you can type the selected value from the database

Answer (score 0):

Tofandel
Great Job! I was able to make use of these simple lines of code to represent my rating clearly thanks but the .stars{ } didn't apply so I just added a little to make it sweet. smile...

```
echo $rating="4.7";
echo "<span class='stars'>"
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
    if ( round( $rating - .25 ) >= $i ) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star' style='font-size:20px;color:#ff9f00;'></i>"; //fas fa-star for v5
    } elseif ( round( $rating + .25 ) >= $i ) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-o' style='font-size:20px;color:#ff9f00;'></i>";//fas fa-star-half-alt for v5
    } else {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o' style='font-size:20px;color:#ff9f00;'></i>"; //far fa-star for v5
    }
}
echo '</span>';

Thank you
```